# Why is my async jQuery ajax call blocking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have read many similar questions to mine from long ago but have yet to find the answer to my problem, so apologies if it sounds so familiar.

I have a Laravel/PHP web app which loads in an excel file of transactions. These are processed as either success or failure. In development it takes about two seconds per transaction. A typical file has about 40 transactions. I am now wanting to use the Bootstrap progress bar to provide feedback to the user about how far along the processing is going.

I have a page with a button to fire the import, previously file selection and things have happened, so I can just call the backend URL (audit.import) with the correct parameters and the upload will happen and work. So what I have done, is create a URL to return the status of the upload from the server (loadprogress). The plan being that the loadprogress will be called via ajax and the magic of js setTimeout, in order to poll the backend. Once we see all records have been successful or not, then the poll can end.

The problem is, the loadprogress poll fires regularly, right up until I press the button to start the main file load. Then it fails to fire again until the main file load has completed, thus removing the planned use for the progress meter.

My javascript looks like this,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var fullname = '<?php echo $fullname; ?>';

                    $("#ajaxButton").click(function(event) {
                        $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            }
                        });
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/audit.import/1/' + fullname,
                            type: 'POST',
                            async: true,
                        }).always(function(xhr, status) {
                            console.log("Import complete with status of " + status);
                        });
                        console.log("sent async call to perform audit");
                    });

                    (function loadProgress() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: '/loadprogress',
                        }).done(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        }).then(function() {
                            setTimeout(loadProgress, 100);
                        })
                    })();
                });
            </script>
```

I am on a mac in safari, but have tried chrome on mac with the same results.

Any assistance would be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might have better success with [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

Comment: to be honest, it's probably an issue with the server side code

Comment: How are you verifying the behaviour you're seeing? Are you using the _Network_ panel in your browser dev-tools? If so, what exactly do you see happening?

Comment: @bravo for the win. Thanks mate, it does indeed appear to be because I am running a single threaded dev server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a server side problem. I was running on a single threaded test server which means there was no second thread for my second process. Hence the block. By default the test Laravel server that comes with the install is only single threaded. A fact I had missed in my setup of the test server.